# How to get row index on itemdblclick Extjs4

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I m trying trying to get row index so that i could fetch the value of the record in grid. On double click i m able to show alert with index of the row . I went through sencha docs but found no method to get the rowindex. I want data of each cell of record to be filled in textfield of form.

```
 itemdblclick: function (view, record, htmlItem, index, eventObject, opts) {   
     //var j1 = record.data.name;
     //var r1 = this.view.getSelectionModel( ) ;
     //var w = this.getData('index');
     alert("idx= " + index);
     //var RI = getIndex( );
     //var r1 = get(index);
     //Ext.Msg.alert('Hello');
     var win = new Ext.Window({
         title: 'hello',
         xtype: 'form',
         items: [..]
     });
     win.show();
 })
```

Comment: Your question does not make sense. You get both the record and the index as parameters to your function. What are you missing?

Comment: @dbrin It seems that u didn't got my question.Give one more try. And even than if u think that it doesn't make sense go ahead and give a negative vote.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @dbrin data is being populated in grid from local server. on double click of record a new form is open which has some textfield and a super box select . i want the data in the record  to be loaded in the form . iwas trying to fetch data of each cell through different methods but i was not able to.

Comment: that was not clear from your post at all. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [store.getAt(index)](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getAt), or alternatively [store.getById(record.get('id'))](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getById)

Either of those seem like they'd work for you.

Comment: i m populating data in grid through ajax call . i'll try both the method above u suggested. Thankx

Answer (score 0):

```
win.down('form').loadRecord(record);
```

The `record` comes from the doubleclick event and is passed into your function.